# How do I use Mono WebAssembly to run a simple .NET method in browser?

Tags: .net, mono, webassembly

Let's say I have a .NET dll file on the server, that has this simple class:

```cs
public static class C {
    public static int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;
}
```

I want to invoke `C.Add` in browser using Mono's WebAssembly support.
(assume that I can download the dll into browser, e.g. with `fetch`)

Questions:

1. What .js/.wasm files are required for Mono and where do I get those?
2. Once everything is loaded, how do I actually invoke `C.Add` from JS?

I checked npm but I haven't found Mono WASM there.

Note: I already have a dll, so I'm interested in WASM IL interpreter and not WASM AOT build.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I found.

#### Obtain Mono WASM

- The steps are described here: [docs/getting-started/obtain-wasm-sdk.md](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/33d6380103576782901c208e68488cc0b5af433b/sdks/wasm/docs/getting-started/obtain-wasm-sdk.md)
- Short summary: you have to download and unpack a [build from Jenkins](https://jenkins.mono-project.com/job/test-mono-mainline-wasm)

Let's call the unpacked folder `WASM-SDK`.

**Note**: you can skip following steps if you run `packager.exe` as described in Mono docs, but I want to describe the manual approach here for better understanding.

#### Prepare .NET dlls

Put the following dlls under your site root (lets say under `managed` folder):

- Main dll that contains `class C`, let's call it `app.dll`
- BCL dependencies, in this case you only need:

  1. `WASM-SDK\wasm-bcl\wasm\mscorlib.dll`
  2. `WASM-SDK\wasm-bcl\wasm\Facades\netstandard.dll`
  3. `WASM-SDK\framework\WebAssembly.Bindings.dll`

#### Prepare Web files

1. Copy `mono.js` and `mono.wasm` from `WASM-SDK\release` under your site root
2. Register your `Module` and import `mono.js`:

```
<script>
window.Module = {};
window.Module.onRuntimeInitialized = () => {
   const config = {
       vfsPrefix: "managed",
       deployPrefix: "managed",
       enableDebugging: 0
   };
   const assemblies = [
       'app.dll',
       'mscorlib.dll',
       'WebAssembly.Bindings.dll',
       'netstandard.dll'
   ];
   MONO.mono_load_runtime_and_bcl(
       config.vfsPrefix,
       config.deployPrefix,
       config.enableDebugging,
       assemblies,
       () => {
          Module.mono_bindings_init("[WebAssembly.Bindings]WebAssembly.Runtime");
          const add = Module.mono_bind_static_method("[app] C:Add");

          // ⬇️ This is what calls C.Add():
          console.log('C.Add:', add(1, 2));
       }
   )
};
<script>
<script async src="mono.js"></script>
```

3. If using IIS, make sure that there is a `application/wasm` mime type register for the `.wasm` extension.

#### All done

Now once you open your HTML you should see `C.Add: 3` logged in the browser console.

Comment: in Obtain Mono WASM step, "build from Jenkins" ---> The link has expired.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to run Mono WebAssembly these days is by using .NET 7 or later.  The Mono runtime is now part of .NET (since .NET 6), and work on the WebAssembly support continues in the [dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) repo.

- If you're building a complete app and you would like to use a UI framework, consider using [Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-webassembly) or perhaps [Uno](https://platform.uno/)
- If you would like to use .NET in your own JavaScript application or library in the browser that uses another framework, you may be able to use the `wasm-experimental` workload in .NET 7 to [Use .NET 7 from any JavaScript app](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/use-net-7-from-any-javascript-app-in-net-7/)
- There is also work to support .NET running on WASI, although as of .NET 8 Preview 3 nothing is officially supported yet.  However there is [active work in that area](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/65895) too.